# Python script to add new vaule at the end of each row in the csv output file based on the checking conditon

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a python script to add new value at the end of a row in CSV file that produced by the initial part of the script.
The CSV file has values like below

```
name,isactive,ful_name,emailaddress
rajesh,active,Rajesh Pidikiti,myemail@corp.####.com
james,active,James wood,mail@mail.com
```

I need to consider the name of each row and check the user has admin privileges (by running one curl command) or not. If the user is admin then add admin as new value at end of the row (new column). If not then add user as the new value.

The output will be like this

```
name,isactive,ful_name,emailaddress,isadmin 
rajesh,active,Rajesh Pidikiti,myemail@corp.####.com,admin 
james,active,James wood,mail@mail.com,user
```

I have tried by creating function and for a loop but not successful. I'm okay to either Appending the results to input or creating a new output file.

This what I have written so far.

```
def to_add_new_col(input_file,output_file)
        with open(input_file, 'rb') as infile:
                with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile:
                        reader = csv.reader(infile, lineterminator='\n')
                        writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')

                        check_and_add(reader, writer)

def check_and_add(reader, writer)
        for i in reader:
                for field in (i)
                        if(curl_result(field):
                                i=admin
                        else
                                i=user

                writer.writerow(i)
```

Comment: Could you please show the code you've already tried before?

Comment: import csv  def to_add_new_col(input_file,output_file) with open(input_file, 'rb') as infile: with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile: reader = csv.reader(infile, lineterminator='\n') writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')   check_and_add(reader, writer) def check_and_add(reader, writer) for i in reader: for field in (i) if(curl_result(field): i=admin else  i=user  writer.writerow(i)             This is what I have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default settings for both the CSV reader and writer. First you need to read in the header row, add the new column heading and then write it to your output CSV file. Then for each row in your input CSV file, pass the `is_admin()` function a user to test which returns either `admin` or `user` (I have created a dummy function which just tests if the user name has an even or odd number of characters). This returned value can then be added to the list of values in the row and written to the output.

If you are not sure how this is working, add a print statement to help. For example add `print(row)`:

```
import csv

def is_admin(user):
    """ Test if user is admin (replace with your curl test) """
    return 'admin' if len(user) % 2 == 0 else 'user'


with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader) + ['isadmin'])

    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(row + [is_admin(row[0])])
```

This would give you an `output.csv` file containing:

```
name,isactive,ful_name,emailaddress,isadmin
rajesh,active,Rajesh Pidikiti,myemail@corp.####.com,admin
james,active,James wood,mail@mail.com,user
```